# ColorPickerPreference Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library

I use in my project [ColorPickerPreference](https://github.com/attenzione/android-ColorPickerPreference) library and until today everything worked well . But now I see the compilation error

> Error:(1, 0) Cause: com/android/build/gradle/LibraryPlugin :
>   Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

in file

> MyPath\AndroidStudioProjects\MyApp\app\libs\ColorPickerPreference\ColorPickerPreference\build.gradle
>
> echo %JAVA_HOME% show me C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79
>
> and java -version
>
> java version "1.7.0_79" Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build
>   1.7.0_79-b15) Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.79-b02, mixed mode)

As I understand this dependencie uses a different version of Java but why I have no problems before? And how I can fix it?

just in case show ColorPickerPreference\build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 7
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this problem. It appears in app/build.gradle and in app/libs/ColorPickerPreference/build.gradle   was

classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:+'

I changed to a specific version classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'

and it helped.